# Verification code doesn't work in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, infrared

I am new to Arduino and I'm trying to make a program that receives IR codes from a TV remote, uses them as a 4 number pass code lighting up a LED as you press each button. And then comparing the code to a hard-coded one. In this case 1234.
I made a function to verify that the value entered is equal to the pass. If so, light up a green LED and else, light up a red one.
However, even if I input the correct code, only the red led lights up.
Here is my whole code as I'm not sure which part of it is the one causing problems:

```
const int pass[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int value[4] = {};
int digitNum = 0;
int input;


void loop() 
{
  value[digitNum] = input; //where input is a number between 0 and 9
  digitNum++;
  if(digitNum == 1){
    lightFirstLed(); 
  }
  else if(digitNum == 2){
    lightSecondLed();
  }
  else if(digitNum == 3){
    lightThirdLed();
  }
  else if(digitNum == 4){
    lightFourthLed();
    verify();
  }
}

void verify()
{
  bool falseCharacter = false;
  for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    if(value[i] != pass[i]){
      falseCharacter = true;
    }
  }
  if(!falseCharacter){
    lightGreenLed();
  }
  else{
    lightRedLed();
  }
}
```

Functions in the form of `light*Led` actually do what they're supposed to do.
I tried changing the verify function around, that ended up making the green LED the one that always shone. I've been doing this for hours and I'm starting to feel disparate.

I would really appreciate any help. And please tell me if anything I'm doing does not comply with best practices even if it's out of the scope of this question.

For full code and design, here's a link to autodesk's simulator: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/0keqmlhVqNp-mighty-leelo/editel?tenant=circuits?sharecode=vVUD2_4774Lj4PYXh6doFcOqWUMY2URIfW8VXGxutRE=
EDIT: Now reset doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There is far too much code in your question, and it is unlikely that all of it is contributing to your issue.  Please create a [mcve] that shows your problem in as few lines as possible.

Comment: Ok I will try. Though I have no idea what's causing the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: @JoeC is this better?

Comment: Does the Arduino have an IR remote library?

Comment: `410 - The requested page has expired`

Comment: That didn't work. Here's a pastebin https://pastebin.com/nZ42vw7U .

Comment: and  ![a screenshot.]([https://imgur.com/a/Pf3tqZn)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop in `verify` is accessing outside the array:

```
const int pass[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int value[4] = {};

for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
    if(value[i] != pass[i]){
        falseCharacter = true;
    }
}
```

Change `i <= 4` to `i < 4`.  Also, when `falseCharacter` is set to `true`, `break` from the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if(value[i] != pass[i])
    {
        falseCharacter = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Update**

You need an `else` statement in `loop`:

```
void loop(void)
{
    if(irrecv.decode(&results))
    {
        if (results.value == powBtn)
        {
            reset();
        }
        else if (results.value == zeroBtn)
        {
            input = 0;
        }
        else if (results.value == oneBtn)
        {
            input = 1;
        }
        else if (results.value == twoBtn)
        {
            input = 2;
        }
        else if (results.value == threeBtn)
        {
            input = 3;
        }
        else if (results.value == fourBtn)
        {
            input = 4;
        }
        else if (results.value == fiveBtn)
        {
            input = 5;
        }
        else if (results.value == sixBtn)
        {
            input = 6;
        }
        else if (results.value == sevenBtn)
        {
            input = 7;
        }
        else if (results.value == eightBtn)
        {
            input = 8;
        }
        else if (results.value == nineBtn)
        {
            input = 9;
        }
        else
        {
            return; /*** !!! Unrecognized Value !!! ***/
        }

        value[digitNum] = input;
        digitNum++;
        if(digitNum == 1)
        {
            digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
        }
        else if(digitNum == 2)
        {
            digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
        }
        else if(digitNum == 3)
        {
            digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
        }
        else if(digitNum == 4)
        {
            digitalWrite(LED4, HIGH);
            verify();
        }
        else
        {
            if (results.value == powBtn)
            {
                reset();
            }
        }

        // Receive the next value
        irrecv.resume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in `verify` to see what the input of `value` really is?

Comment: It's [0,0,0,0] for some reason.

Comment: Looks like `if (irrecv.decode(&results))` isn't working as expected.

Comment: Where did you get these numbers from? `const int powBtn = 16580863;` etc.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations as to what I should do as a workaround? And what makes you sure the problem is not with my code?

Comment: with this https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/IRrecvDemo/IRrecvDemo.ino

Comment: just in decimal instead of HEX

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint after `if (irrecv.decode(&results))`? See if `results` is all zeroes?

Comment: Did you set the breakpoint here `if (results.value == powBtn)`, to see what the value of `results` is? Your screenshot shows that it's all zeroes.

Comment: Do you have a configuration file? Do you need to set something to `1` such as `DECODE_NEC`.

Comment: I have no idea what a configuration file in arduino is

Comment: Looks like those are being `define`d in `IRremote.h`.

Comment: Do I submit an issue in github?

Comment: I'm not sure, as your using a simulator.

Comment: Now it doesn't work at all. I think it's constantly sending garbage values and that somehow broke it.

Comment: I can't advise you with that. Sorry. Good luck.

Comment: But my reset function still does not work. Here is a pastebin https://pastebin.com/uY3VWXAt